# Ambiguous tag [sign]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [sign](/questions/tagged/sign) tag has no tag wiki and many different usages:

- [Signed/Unsigned numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201555/how-to-set-highest-bit-in-java-short)
- [GPG Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131723/bouncycastle-openpgp-issue)
- [Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751838/adding-a-sign-to-numericupdown-value-like)
- [Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648124/login-signup-using-session-in-grails)
- [Minecraft Bukkit Signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239570/minecraft-bukkit-sign-inventory)

I suggest we burninate it.

Comment: 354 is just a few too many for me to manually remove. But yes, we should totally burninate that tag.

Comment: Pfft.  No, we should keep it.  It's a `[sign]` of a bad question.

Comment: Why do people keep advocating for the retention of smelly tags? Bad questions will smell without the tag too!